# Sql Group by on subquery rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have this table :
***ArretProductionJournee(Id, DateArret,HeureDebut,HeureFin,EnumArret)***
Example :

```
DateArret   ||HeureDebut                 ||HeureFin                 ||EnumArret
2020-11-30  ||2020-11-30 14:00:00.000    ||2020-11-30 15:00:00.000  ||PS
2020-11-30  ||2020-11-30 16:00:00.000    ||2020-11-30 17:00:00.000  ||HI
```

i want to sum the datediff(HeureDebut,HeureFin) in columns for each EnumArret
so i run this query :

```
SELECT ArretProductionJournee.DateArret, 
(select
sum (datediff(minute,ArretProductionJournee.HeureDebut, 
ArretProductionJournee.HeureFin))
where ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'HI')as HI,

(select
sum (datediff(minute,ArretProductionJournee.HeureDebut, 
ArretProductionJournee.HeureFin))
where ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'PS') as PS

FROM            dbo.ArretProductionJournee
                where ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'HI'OR 
                ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'PS'
group by  ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret, dbo.ArretProductionJournee.DateArret
```

Result :

```
DateArret   ||HI   ||   PS
2020-10-30  ||12   ||   NULL
2020-11-30  ||60   ||   NULL
2020-11-30  ||NULL ||   60
```

The result i want is Grouping the sum by the date:

```
DateArret   ||HI   ||   PS
2020-10-30  ||12   ||   0
2020-11-30  ||60   ||   60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select datearret,
    sum(case when enumarret = 'PS' then datediff(minute, heuredebut, heurefin) else 0 end) ps,
    sum(case when enumarret = 'HI' then datediff(minute, heuredebut, heurefin) else 0 end) hi
from dbo.arretproductionjournee
where enumarret in ('PS', 'HI')
group by datearret
```